# how can you take an ArrayList of chars and return all those elements from the ArrayList into a String

Tags: java

This is the code for trying to answer my question. I'm kind of new with ArrayLists. I used a for loop trying to read every element from the Arraylist and put it in the new String "full" but this won't compile. I need some editing. I don't think this code properly works. I used .add so that I can try adding the elements from the String List to String full. This is what tried to do so far.

```
public void String() {

   ArrayList<Character> StringList = new ArrayList<Character>();
   String full;           
   for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       full.add(StringList[i]);
   }
   return full;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `StringBuilder` class, specifically the `append` method:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Answer (score 2):

I suggest

- only use methods which are documented in Javadoc.
- Use StringBuilder to build Strings, not ArrayList of Characters.
- Don't call methods `String` and use camelCase for variables.
- Don't access ArrayList as if it were an array, use `get(i)`

Answer (score 1):

One effective way is to append each character to the string:

```
String myString = "";
for (Character c : myList) {
    myString += c;
}
```

If myList.toString() gives: `[a, b, c, d, e, f]`, then myString gives: `abcdef`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `.add(String)` method in String class as far as i can remember.

But getting elements out of the `ArrayList`, is this what you are looking for?

```
StringList.get(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal way would be:

```
ArrayList<Character> StringList = new ArrayList<Character>();
StringList.add('H');
StringList.add('e');
StringList.add('l');
StringList.add('l');
StringList.add('o');
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(char c : StringList) sb.append(c);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

and here is another way to do it:

```
ArrayList<Character> StringList = new ArrayList<Character>();
StringList.add('H');
StringList.add('e');
StringList.add('l');
StringList.add('l');
StringList.add('o');
System.out.println(StringList.toString().replaceAll("[, \\[\\]]", ""));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [lowerCamelCase](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/lowerCamelCase) as naming convention for name of variables
   and methods.
2. Use `get(index)` of ArrayList to retrieve elements. Don't use it like array.
   It will not work (eg StringList[i] is invalid use StringList.get(i))
3. Read the Java Doc
4. Always try to read and errors (if getting any)